# Is there a performance hit when using JavaScript objects passed to Rust?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, rust

When using Rust in a browser, I can get JavaScript objects and use them inside Rust (using, for instance, the `js!` macro from the [stdweb library](https://github.com/koute/stdweb)).

Do I get a performance hit when using these objects? Should I always copy them to Rust structures?

Comment: Javascript objects are very very dynamic things. There will probably be a performance impact compared to Rust structures.

Answer (score 0):

In Wasm access of Rust `struct` fields is definitely much faster than access of fields of a JS object.

There is a cost of converting a JS object to a Rust `struct`, so if you need to access only one or two fields from a JS object once, then it might be more efficient to do just that rather than to convert the entire object to a Rust `struct` first.

Comment: Do you have any numbers? For instance, accessing a JS object is around 2x slower.